# Rail test case fixtures not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

Rails appears to **not** be loading **any** fixtures for unit or functional tests. I have a simple 'products.yml' that parses and appears correct:

```
ruby:
  title: Programming Ruby 1.9
  description:
    Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic
    language out there. If you need to get working programs
    delivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox.
  price: 49.50
  image_url: ruby.png
```

My controller functional test begins with:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :products

  setup do
    @product = products(:one)    
    @update = {
      :title => 'Lorem Ipsum' ,
      :description => 'Wibbles are fun!' ,
      :image_url => 'lorem.jpg' ,
      :price => 19.95
    }
  end
```

According to the book, Rails should "magically" load the fixtures (as my `test_helper.rb` has `fixtures :all` in it. I also added the explicit fixtures load (seen above). Yes Rails complains:

```
user @ host ~/Dropbox/Rails/depot > rake test:functionals
(in /Somewhere/Users/user/Dropbox/Rails/depot)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -Ilib:test "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/products_controller_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
EEEEEEE
Finished in 0.062506 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_should_create_product(ProductsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for ProductsControllerTest:Class
    /test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:7

  2) Error:
test_should_destroy_product(ProductsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for ProductsControllerTest:Class
    /test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:7
...
```

I did come across the other Rails test fixture question [Rails unit testing doesn't load fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547634/rails-unit-testing-doesnt-load-fixtures), but that leads to a plugin issue (something to do with the order of loading fixtures).

BTW, I am developing on Mac OS X 10.6 with Rail 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7, no additional plugins (beyond the base install).

Any pointers on how to debug, **why** the magic of Rails appears to be failing here? Is it a version problem? Can I trace code into the libraries and find the answer? There are so many "mixin" modules I can't find where the `fixtures` method really lives.

Comment: APIdock is useful for times like this when you need to find method docs.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods/fixtures

Comment: thanks x1a4! apidocks IS a very handy tool that I'll be adding to my toolbox. still not sure what the root cause is though ...

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 3.2, I find that when running a single test file (specifying TEST=/test/unit/foo.rb), the fixtures are not loaded.  However when running the tests with

```
ruby -Itest /test/unit/foo.rb
```

the fixtures are loaded as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.1.1, I resolved the issue by setting `self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = true` in test_helper.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Having given up, I tried a reinstall/rebuild onto rail 3.0.0beta3. this resolved the issue. I can only assume this was some kind of version mismatch.