# Rails tests, fixture & class loading order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I have an ActiveRecord class which has scopes dynamically added based on content of another table.

(simplified code example)

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

  Feature.all.each do |feature|
    scope feature.name, ->{joins(:feature).where("feature.name = #{feature.name})}
  end
end
```

Another part of the UI of the app is a "Thing display" that lets you search and apply these feature scopes as part of the search.

This all works fine in the running app.

In tests, however, it seems success depends on what order things are loaded in. Sometimes `Thing` has the expected scopes, other times not. I thought I could force the `Feature` class and fixtures to load first by calling `Feature.count` before any tests run, but this doesn't work.

Is there some way to force the loading of class/fixtures to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure this is not related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28515064/2116518) or [this](https://sanjusoftware.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/rails-fixtures-load-order/)?

Comment: @NicNilov I'm not running Postgres, I don't have foreign key constraints in my db, and the tests pass/fail depending on the order of execution of the tests. So those linked issues don't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the goal to make sure fixtures are loaded before classes there is a couple of directions to explore.

One is to detect when fixtures finish loading and force reload the `Thing` class for it to generate proper scopes. The problem with this is I couldn't find a way to detect the fixtures loaded event. A tangential issue is that an individual class reload in the presence of `config.cache_classes = true` would be quite hacky.

Another, more promising approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598642/2116518) and consists in putting the test runner task in a wrapper which ensures fixtures are loaded first.